# Object iteration and appending to form

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

In this code, I'm getting the json from backend.  Once I find the json availability, I loop and make 5 columns.  Once the columns are made, I append after the legend of my form.

Can this be improved any further?

```
if(data.hasOwnProperty("allLocales")){

            var col0 = $("<fieldset />"), 
                col1 = $("<fieldset />"),
                col2 = $("<fieldset />"),
                col3 = $("<fieldset />"),
                col4 = $("<fieldset />");

            $.map(data["allLocales"], function(value, i){

                var name = value.name;

                if(i % 5 === 0 ){
                    col0.append($("<label />").text(name).prepend($("<input type='checkbox' />").attr("value", name)));
                }else if(i % 5 === 1){
                    col1.append($("<label />").text(name).prepend($("<input type='checkbox' />").attr("value", name)));
                }else if(i % 5 === 2){
                    col2.append($("<label />").text(name).prepend($("<input type='checkbox' />").attr("value", name)));
                }else if(i % 5 === 3){
                    col3.append($("<label />").text(name).prepend($("<input type='checkbox' />").attr("value", name)));
                }else if(i % 5 === 4){
                    col4.append($("<label />").text(name).prepend($("<input type='checkbox' />").attr("value", name)));
                }

            })

            $("form legend").after(col0,col1,col2,col3,col4).end().find("span.submit").css({display:"block"});
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather use an array. This allows you to write the following:

```
if (data.hasOwnProperty("allLocales")) {
    var col = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        col[i] = $("<fieldset />");
    }
    $.map(data["allLocales"], function (value, i) {
        var name = value.name;
        $col[i % 5].append($("<label />").text(name).prepend($("<input type='checkbox' />").attr("value", name)));
    })
    $("form legend").after(col).end().find("span.submit").css({display: "block"});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First you should not create on function for each column.
In place of :

```
var col0 = $("<fieldset />"), 
    col1 = $("<fieldset />"),
    col2 = $("<fieldset />"),
    col3 = $("<fieldset />"),
    col4 = $("<fieldset />");
```

You should use :

```
var col_type  = "<fieldset />";
```

```
var cols      = {}
```

And then add it to your JSON :

```
cols["col"+ i % 5]  = $(col_type)...
```

So, you'll get a JSON object of this form :

```
{
  "col0":   <YOUR_jQuery element>,
  "col1":   <YOUR_jQuery element>,
  "col2":   <YOUR_jQuery element>,
  "col3":   <YOUR_jQuery element>,
  "col4":   <YOUR_jQuery element>
}
```

JSON are not support in jQuery for after() iteration. You must use an Array.

```
cols.push($(col_type)...)
```

And you won't need one variable for each new column.

<strike>Could you give a sample of your data.allLocales ?
And a sample of your HTML code ?</strike>

And no **if(data.hasOwnProperty("allLocales"))** is needed

Described :

```
for( column in data["allLocales"] ) {
  var name = data["allLocales"][column].name

  $("form legend").after(
    $("<fieldset />")
    .append(
      $("<label />")
      .text(name)
      .prepend(
        $("<input type='checkbox' />")
        .attr("value", name)
      )
    )
  )
 .end()
 .find("span.submit")
 .css({display: "block"});
}
```

Shorter :

```
for( column in data["allLocales"] ) {
  var name = data["allLocales"][column].name
  $("form legend").after($("<fieldset />").append(
    $("<label />").text(name).prepend($("<input type='checkbox' />").attr("value", name)))).end().find("span.submit").css({display: "block"}
  )
}
```